# XGBoost: split data in train and test

Tags: python, pyspark, xgboost

I am using the python interface for XGBoost for building models. I have a dataset that I am reading in using `xgb.DMatrix(data_path)`. I need to split this data into train and test (and validation, if required). But most of the implementations I have seen are of the form

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix('')
dtest = xgb.DMatrix('')
```

I couldn't find a way to where we can read in the dataset and then split 'em into train, test (and validation) sets.

Furthermore, is it possible to perform stratified sampling while splitting into train and test?

I need to know this because I have slightly larger datasets and currently I am reading it in using spark, splitting them up, storing on disk and then reading from there. Is there a way I can do it without having to go through Pyspark and reading from the hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

I would use sklearn's `train_test_split`, which also has a stratify parameter, and then put the results into `dtrain` and `dtest`.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=y)

import xgboost as xgb
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)
```

See implementation here: [A Simple XGBoost Tutorial Using the Iris Dataset](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/03/simple-xgboost-tutorial-iris-dataset.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can always read in data from HDF5 files using `pandas` (see [pandas.HDStore](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/api.html#hdfstore-pytables-hdf5)) then do splitting using sklearn (either simple random or stratified train/train split, see `stratify` parameter of [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)). And then you can feed the pandas DataFrame objects directly into the [sklearn API of xgboost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) or convert those into `xgboost.DMatrix` and use those in the native training API